# Retrieve user_meta and copy to post_meta

Tags: post-meta, user-meta, geo-data

As geo mashup only retrieves post_meta,  I am trying to copy over the geo_location from a custom registration field into the meta for page containing the map.

The code I am using is:

```
<?php 
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
$user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
$user_location = the_author_meta('geo_address', $user->ID);
 add_post_meta( 463, 'geo_move', $user_location); 

}}
?>
```

This creates the post meta, but the value is written as a blank, so it looks like $user_location isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `get_users_of_blog` has been deprecated, so you should use [`get_users`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) instead, or run a `WP_User_Query`.

After that, `the_author_meta` **echo** the meta value, not return anything. To **return** the meta you should use [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

```
$blogusers = get_users( $args ); // for args see codex

if ($blogusers) {
  foreach ( $blogusers as $bloguser ) {
    $user_location = get_the_author_meta('geo_address', $bloguser->ID );
    $has_meta = get_post_meta(463, 'geo_move', true);
    if ($user_location && ! $has_meta) add_post_meta( 463, 'geo_move', $user_location);
  }
}
```

Comment: And that's done it! A supplemental query - if I add this as a function, will it duplicate the fields every time the site is refreshed? I'm testing it in a page template and every refresh duplicates the content

Comment: @PaulAston I've edited the answer to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Above and beyond! That's great!